# Get array from nested json value objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, lodash

I've been searching an answer for that but didn't found it.

I have an array like:

```
const data2 = [{
    "abc":{
            companyCity:"Cupertino",
            conpanyName:"Apple"
        }
    },
    {
    "def":{
            companyCity:"Mountain View",
            conpanyName:"Google"
        }
    }
]
```

And I'd like to convert to and array like omiting the parent keys:

```
const data3 = [
    {
        companyCity:"Cupertino",
        companyName:"Apple",
    },
    {
        companyCity:"Mountain View",
        companyName:"Google"
    }
]
```

Perhaps, libraries like lodash have a method to achieve that, but didn't find it. Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: There is no JSON in your question, the corresponding tag probably should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the array with `Array.flatMap()` (or lodash's `_.flatMap()`), and get the an the inner object of each item using `Object.values()` (or `_.values()`):

```js
const data = [{"abc":{"companyCity":"Cupertino","conpanyName":"Apple"}},{"def":{"companyCity":"Mountain View","conpanyName":"Google"}}]

const result = data.flatMap(Object.values)

console.log(result)
```