# Convert array of objects to array of values

Tags: javascript

I have next array:

```
[
        {
            "1": "somedata1"
        },
        {
            "2": "somedata2"
        },
        {
            "3": "somedata3"
        },
]
```

I need to convert it to `[somedata1,somedata2,somedata3]`. What is best way to do this?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Can the objects have more than one property each?

Comment: Look into Object.values() and Array.map()

Comment: [Get array from nested json value objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888093)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
var data = [{ 1: "somedata1" }, { 2: "somedata2" }, { 3: "somedata3" }],
    values = data.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go.

```
yourArray = [..] // the stuff you put there.
yourArray.map((item, index) => item[index+1])
```